# MySQL date validity

Tags: mysql, sql, function, date, time

Does MySQL provide any function which verifies the validity of a date? The `DATE` function returns `NULL` upon provision of the invalid date 2013-02-30 for example. However, I am also using `STR_TO_DATE` simultaneously, which mysteriously stops `DATE` from working correctly.

```
SELECT DATE('2013-02-30'); NULL
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('2013-02-30', '%Y-%m-%d'); NOT NULL
SELECT DATE('2013-02-40'); NULL
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('2013-02-40', '%Y-%m-%d'); NULL
SELECT DATE(STR_TO_DATE('2013-02-30', '%Y-%m-%d')); NOT NULL
```

Why does `STR_TO_DATE` halt `DATE`'s functionality and is there some workaround to verify if a date is valid when using `STR_TO_DATE` (which I am obligated to use)?

I have stumbled upon the answer in the meantime: apparently the `DATE` function skips a few validation checks, when the data type is already that of 'date' (`STR_TO_DATE` converts strings to date data types). Therefore, converting the date to a string after having parsed it to the correct format with `STR_TO_DATE`, does the trick:

`@valid_date = NOT ISNULL(DATE(CONVERT(STR_TO_DATE('2013-02-29', '%Y-%m-%d'), CHAR)))`.

Comment: Please provide some more context:  What is the data flow you are trying to validate?

Comment: @wallyk A date which may be formatted arbitrarily should be firstly passed to the STR_TO_DATE function along with its format and should have its validity verified second. Just solved the problem though, see the edit.

Comment: If you pull a date out of some database field, you already know it is either NULL or valid.  Why would you validate it?

Comment: @wallyk The values are imported from large CSV files, which need validation.

Comment: interesting question... `DAY(STR_TO_DATE('2013-02-31', '%Y-%m-%d'))` returns 31, but `DAY(STR_TO_DATE('2013-02-31', '%Y-%m-%d') + INTERVAL 0 DAY)` returns 3... it looks like STR_TO_DATE does not return a "real" DATE field... maybe it's a bug?

Answer (score 2):

It is very difficult to verify if a field is a date because of all the different possible date formats that would need to be taken into account. BUT if you know that the field date formats are one of these:

```
'yyyy-mm-dd'
'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss'
'yyyy-mm-dd whatever'
```

This code will help you:

```
 SELECT count(*) FROM `table` 
 WHERE DATE(STR_TO_DATE(`column`, '%Y-%m-%d')) IS NOT NULL
 AND `column` NOT REGEXP '^[0-9\.]+$'
```

Basically :

- the first condition tells you if is a date, but unfortunately doesn't exclude numbers (ex: `DATE(STR_TO_DATE(**1**, '%Y-%m-%d')) = '2001-00-00'`
- the second ensures that numbers are excluded, which leaves you with dates only that follow the formats above.

If `count(*)` is `>0` then it's a date, if it is `0` it's something else.

**Note**
This method works for strings of any date format as long as you know in advance what format they follow (which I know is not always the case but still helpful). Just replace the format `a priori` in `STR_TO_DATE`

Comment: Actualy, in my version of MySQL with my settings, the STR_TO_DATE crashes the query if an invalid date is found. Only the regex would suffice in my oppinion.

Answer (score 0):

i can't understand your purpose clearly, maybe this is a idea;
 SELECT DATE_FORMAT(yourFiled, '%Y-%m-%d') days FROM  yourTable GROUP BY days;
this is not null; you can change it. some like

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(yourFiled, '%Y-%m-%d') days FROM  yourTable WHERE yourFiled > '2013-9-23 00:00:00' GROUP By days;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`SELECT DATE(STR_TO_DATE('2013-00-30', '%Y-%m-%d')); --is also NOT NULL`